# The maximum of the sum of fixed-length substrings in a Bernoulli process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution, gambling, extreme-value-theorem

Suppose a biased coin (probability of head being $p$) was flipped $n$ times. For a fixed positive integer $k$ ($k<n$), there exists $(n-k+1)$ consecutive subsequences. I am interested in the greatest number of heads which appear in any $k$-element subsequences taken from the particular outcome of n flips.

Concretely, when $n=100,k=30,p=0.5$, we have $X_1,X_2,...,X_{100} \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$ i.i.d.,and I am interested in the random variable

$$
Y=max_{1\leq k \leq 71}(\sum_{i=k}^{k+29} X_i)
$$

I would appreciate any advice on how to calculate the distribution or expectation of $Y$, both analytically or asymptotically ($n \rightarrow \infty$ with $k/n$ remains fixed). This is actually the maximum of some dependent binomial variables with some known structure.

Thank you again!

Comment: Just to be clear, your random variable $Y$ depends for its definition on each of $n,k,p$ and is, for a given outcome of n flips of the coin, the greatest number of heads which appear in any k=element subsequences taken from the particular outcome of n flips. Please respond as to whether that is correct.

Comment: the question is far from clear, what is a "head pattern"? Perhaps its a subsequence of length $k$ of consecutive heads?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes that's right. Thank you so much for your attention and apologies for my vague expressions.

Comment: @Masacroso Hi. Thank you so much for your attention! The "head pattern" just means the number of heads. Please check the concrete example I given when $n=100$ and $k=30$ in the problem.      For example, when $n=6$, $k=3$, when the realization is "TTTTTT", then $Y=0$.  When the realization is "THTTHT", the consecutive subsequences with length $k=3$ are "THT","HTT","TTH","THT", and among which the "H" appears at most once, so $Y=1$ now. When the realization is "THHHTT", $Y=3$ since there exists "HHH" in the sequence.  Please let me know if my explanation is not clear enough. Thank you so much!